# Can Google Apps admins monitor the chat history of users?

Tags: gmail, privacy, google-workspace-for-business, google-hangouts, google-hangouts-chat

My company uses Google Apps for all employees, so all have `example@companyname.com` as their official email address. I understand that there would be an admin for the Google Apps.

Can the admin monitor/track the chat history of employees of the company?

Comment: Yes;  The admin can simply reset the account's password.

Comment: @Ramhound : Thanks. But my question was whether the admin will have the privilege to monitor/track the chat history of other users ?

Comment: Yes;  They can.  The admin has access to everything.

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/

> The Google Apps Email Audit API allows Google Apps administrators to audit a user's email, email drafts, **and archived chats**. In addition, a domain administrator can retrieve account login information and download a user's mailbox.